# Do they have the same limit?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, convolution

Suppose $a(\cdot)\in L^p$ and is symmetric and $b(\cdot)\in L^q$, where $1/p+2/q=2$, $p,q\ge 1$. Consider the quantity $Q_T=$
$$
\frac{1}{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx\int_{[-T,T]^2}d\mathbf{v}\int_{[-T,T]^2}d\mathbf{u}~ a(u_1-v_1)b(u_1-x)b(v_1-x)a(u_2-v_2)b(u_2-x)b(v_2-x).
$$
Consider also $P_T=$
$$
\frac{1}{T}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx\int_{[-T,T]^2}d\mathbf{v}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}d\mathbf{u}~ a(u_1-v_1)b(u_1-x)b(v_1-x)a(u_2-v_2)b(u_2-x)b(v_2-x)\\
=\frac{1}{T}\int_{[-T,T]^2}d\mathbf{v} \int_{\mathbb{R}}dx~ h(v_1-x)h(v_2-x)=\frac{1}{T}\int_{[-T,T]^2}d\mathbf{v} ~r(v_1-v_2)
$$
where $h=(a\ast b)\cdot b$ and $r(v)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(v+x)h(x) dx$.

Note that by Holder's inequality and Young's inequality, one has
$$
\|r\|_1\le \|h\|_1^2\le \left(\|(a\ast b)\|_{q^*} \|b\|_{q}\right)^2 \le \|a\|_p^2  \|b\|_{q}^4<\infty,
$$
where $1/q+1/q^*=1$ and $1+1/q^*=1/p+1/q$. Then because $r(\cdot)$ is symmetric, one has by a change of variable:
$$
P_T=2\int_{-2T}^{2T} \left(1-\frac{|v|}{2T}\right) r(v)dv \rightarrow 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} r(v) dv
$$
by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

The question is to show $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}Q_T=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} r(v) dv$, or whether it holds under some additional conditions.

Comment: And where exactly do you have any problems? Just assume that everything is compactly supported (the influence of the tails is small because of the norm bound you quoted), after which the only chance for the pairs $(v_1,v_2)$ to lead to different values in the intermediate integrations when computing $P_T$ and $Q_T$ will be to stay in a constant size neighborhoods of the corners of $[-T,T]^2$, from where, due to the division by $T$, they cannot influence anything.

Comment: @fedja Thanks a lot. What you said makes sense.